# Android set dynamically elements in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Hi I got a problem with the RelativeLayout. The idea is to define a title bar in the XML code on top of the screen and then add a textview element BELOW this bar on the left side but when I add this TextView in the java code it is always displayed in the top left corner of the display (means it is set over the title bar). Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
 <ScrollView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
     </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>



         RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.main);

        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++) {

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        tv.setId(i);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );

        if (i == 0)
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.title);
        else 
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i-1);

        rl.addView(tv, params);
    }
```

Comment: SOLVED!!!! puuuhhhh...after a long fight I finally won ;), if anyone is interested in the solution:  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); this one is the correct definition and the for loop has to start with i=2 (worked for me, DONT KNOW WHY!! ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add an ID to the textview as well, even though you won't have to reference it. Also you can addView and set parameters in one call:

```
tv.setId(123);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.title);
rl.addView(tv, params);
```

Comment: Thank you that worked but only for a single element...I tried to add TextViews in a for-loop now and again then the first element gets added again in the top left corner and all elements have an ID:

Comment: I updated the Code and I was wondering why the inserting which a for loop does not work even if the TextViews have an ID?